# How to compare values in each list object, then output corresponding matching values with the indices of list objects that have corresponding values?

Tags: r

I'd like to compare the values of all the different list objects and then output or record the matching values with corresponding list object indices that have the matching value in program R.

Here is the code:

```
a <- c(10,23,50,7,3) 
b <- c(1,1,2,2,3) 
c <- c(33,24,4,10,1) 
d <- c(1,4,7,8,3) 
y <- c() 
z <- c() 
r <- list() 
table <- data.frame(a,b,c,d) 

for (i in 1:5){   for (j in 3:4){
    x <-  table$b[j] 
    for (l in which(table$b == x)){
      if (abs((table$c[j] - table$a[i])-table$d[l])<10)
      {y <- rbind(y, table[j,])}}
    z <- y}   y <- c()   r[[i]] <- z}
```

The output:

```
> r
[[1]]
   a b  c d
4  7 2 10 8
41 7 2 10 8

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
   a b  c d
4  7 2 10 8
41 7 2 10 8

[[5]]
    a b  c d
3  50 2  4 7
31 50 2  4 7
4   7 2 10 8
41  7 2 10 8
```

I'd like to record the matching values between list objects and also the indices of the list objects that have these matching values. For example in this instance r[[1]] and r[[4]] have matching vector value `7 2 10 8`, I'd like to write in the data frame both the vector and the indices of list object that have this value. How to do this?

EDIT.
I'd like the output to be a vector whose first element would be the matching vectors' 3rd value (c column) and the rest of the elements would be indices of the list objects.

In this case:

```
10
1
4
```

Comment: " I'd like to write in the data frame both the vector and the indices of list object that have this value" --- can you clarify where you want to do that and what it would look like? Maybe show it included in your output